# How to get state for multiple keyBy in flink using queryable state client?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink 1.4.2 and I have one scenario in which I need to use two keys.
For e.g.

```
KeyedStream<UsageStatistics, Tuple> keyedStream = stream.keyBy("clusterId", "ssid");
usageCounts = keyedStream.process(new CustomProcessFunction(windowSize,queryableStateName));
```

Value Description would

```
ValueStateDescriptor<SsidTotalUsage> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor(queryableStateName, SsidTotalUsage.class);
        descriptor.setQueryable(queryableStateName);
```

Can anyone please suggest me to get state using queryable state client for multiple keys in flink?

Below QueryableClient is working well for a single key 'clusterId'.

```
kvState = queryableStateClient.getKvState(JobID.fromHexString(jobId), queryableStateName, clusterId, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, descriptor);
```

What should be the ***type_info*** for multiple keys? Any suggestion/example or reference related to this will be very helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

I have given TypeHint in valueStateDescription.

**In Flink Job:**

```
TypeInformation<SsidTotalUsage> typeInformation = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<SsidTotalUsage>() {});

ValueStateDescriptor<SsidTotalUsage> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor(queryableStateName, typeInformation);
```

**On Client Side:**

```
ValueStateDescriptor<SsidTotalUsage> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor(queryableStateName, typeInformation);
```

I have two key so I had used **Tuple2** class and set the value of my keys like below. 
**Note:** If you have more than two keys then you have to select Tuple3, Tuple4 class according to your keys.

```
 Tuple2<String, String> tuple = new Tuple2<>();
 tuple.f0 = clusterId;
 tuple.f1 = ssid;
```

Then I have provided TypeHint.

```
TypeHint<Tuple2<String, String>> typeHint = new TypeHint<Tuple2<String, String>>() {};

CompletableFuture<ValueState<SsidTotalUsage>> kvState = queryableStateClient.getKvState(JobID.fromHexString(jobId), queryableStateName, tuple, typeHint, descriptor);
```

In Above code, **getState** method will return ***ImmutableValueState***
so I need to get the my pojo like below.

```
ImmutableValueState<SsidTotalUsage> state = (ImmutableValueState<SsidTotalUsage>) kvState.get();

totalUsage = state.value();
```

Comment: thanks for posting the solution to your own problem, that's helpful to others. Was the Flink documentation missing this info? If so, please open a Jira issue to add it, as then it would benefit even more people, thanks